# Is it possible to transfer ownership of a Google Crisis Map from one user to another?

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating a Google Crisis Map for an Emergency Management Department. I don't want to go through all the steps of adding layers, etc only to find out they can't maintain and control the map I create. Can I continue to set up the map and then transfer the map I'm creating to *their Google account* later?

(Or, can I add them as editors and then promote them to owner or something fancy like that?)

Comment: google-maps is not the best tag for this question, google-crisis-maps or google.org would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you click the `Collaborate` button, and choose them as owner, or editor....

[image]

Comment: Thanks for finding that!

Comment: You're more than welcome. Let us know if you got further questions. The community is always happy to help.